# Using data tables inside example tables in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I am working on automation test cases using BDD Cucumber. In my test cases I am using scenario outline as follows:

```
Scenario Outline: My test case
Given: My data is ready
When : My data is <r1>, <r2>, <r3>
Then: My data is <valid>

Examples:
|r1| r2|r3| valid |
|1 | 2 | 3| valid |
```

Now I want to add many entries of my data in "When" which will make "when" very long. Is it possible, I can use data table inside this example table so that my data is passed and statement does not become too lengthy? I searched for this on official docs, but didn't got any reference to use data tables inside example tables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to put the example tokens in the data table cells:

```
Scenario Outline: My test case
    Given: My data is ready
    When : My data is:
        | Field | Value |
        | R1    | <r1>  |
        | R2    | <r2>  |
        | R3    | <r3>  |
Then: My data is <valid>

Examples:
    | r1 | r2 | r3 | valid |
    | 1  | 2  | 3  | valid |
```

Comment: I'm using the same method. But in step definition, everything is coming as string. I want the column r1, r1, r3 to be an Integer and valid column as string. Is it possible?

Comment: @RAMESHKUMAR: Yes it is possible. Please post a question with a [repro]. I cruise the [tag:specflow] tag regularly here, so I'll probably see it quickly.

Comment: I see this question is tagged [tag:cucumber], which is another tag I frequent as well.